# How to force drupal 7 to load HTTPS assets?

Tags: ssl

Environment:
apache + ssl + domain access

Our drupal 7 site uses domain access multiple sub domains
our server is SSL enabled

if I do not set $base_url in settings.php then all of our assets our loaded via HTTP and the user receives a mixed content error

If I DO set $base_url users are redirected to the default subdomain (e.g. foo.blah.com) instead of their current domain (e.g. bar.blah.com)

My question is, how do I force drupal to load all assets via HTTPS?

That way I can uncomment the #base_url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated settings.php with: $base_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

Comment: This is a great way to ensure all resources are requested over https if you are using the [domain access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain). In a project i work on this module kept trying to load css/js etc... over http instead of https, regardless of the activation of the https proto in the domain settings or the various ways of forcing https in the settings.php file.

Comment: Drupal 7 doesn't use $base_url so this setting does nothing, $base_url is a Drupal 6 artifact.

Answer (score 1):

if everything(SERVER AND HOST SETTINGS)  is ok just `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` in your `settings.php`.

[According to  Enabling HTTP Secure (HTTPS)](https://www.drupal.org/https-information)

> Drupal configuration :
>
> If you want to support mixed-mode HTTPS and HTTP sessions open up sites/default/settings.php and add $conf['https'] = TRUE;. This
>   enables you use the same session over HTTP and HTTPS both -- but with
>   two cookies where the HTTPS cookie is sent over HTTPS only. You will
>   need to use contributed modules like securepages to do anything useful
>   with this mode, like submitting forms over HTTPS and so on. While your
>   HTTP cookie is still vulnerable to all usual attacks, a hijacked
>   insecure session cookie can only be used to gain authenticated access
>   to the HTTP site. It will not be valid on the HTTPS site. Whether this
>   is a problem or not depends on the needs of your site and the various
>   module configurations. For example, if all forms are set to go through
>   HTTPS and your visitors can see the same information as logged in
>   users then this is not a problem.
>
> For even better security, leave $conf['https'] at the default value (FALSE) and send all authenticated traffic through HTTPS and use
>   HTTP for anonymous sessions. Once again contributed modules like
>   Secure Login or 443 Session can help you here. Drupal 7 automatically
>   enables the session.cookie_secure PHP configuration on HTTPS sites,
>   which causes SSL-only secure session cookies to be issued to the
>   browser.
>   For best-possible security, set up your site to only use HTTPS, and respond to all HTTP requests with a redirect to your HTTPS site.
>   $conf['https'] can be left at its default value (FALSE) on pure-HTTPS
>   sites. Even then, HTTPS is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks if
>   the connection starts out as a HTTP connection before being redirected
>   to HTTPS. Use the HSTS module or set the Strict-Transport-Security
>   header in your webserver to help prevent users from accessing the site
>   without HTTPS.

also you can use [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) module

**Description of module :**

> A small process which will redirect the required pages to a SSL version of the page.

**Update**
  also you can  in `settings.php` do: `$base_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];`.

Comment: posting answer below

Comment: @noah Then what happened?

Comment: with the dynamic base_url,
https:// is always loaded, and domain access still has control over setting the subdomain

plus, in the drupal docs it says "or best-possible security, set up your site to only use HTTPS, and respond to all HTTP requests with a redirect to your HTTPS site. $conf['https'] can be left at its default value (FALSE) on pure-HTTPS sites. "

if setting conf[https] is for using mixed mode, we require an https only site. i think there is another issue involved with drupal loading our server assets over http,

Comment: @noah also you can set auto redirect in your custom module in 'hook_init' and redirect every page to `https` ( but I think better way is achieve it in `.htacess` )

Comment: Don't use hook_init. Use .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

The [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) module does this.

> A small process which will redirect the required pages to a SSL version of the page.