# <a> and <img> links not generated as https:

Tags: 7, views

I am new to Drupal and having an issue relating to SSL. The view I'm working with is using the jcarousel module to display images with links.

The data contains a link and image source. All of the links are entered using relative paths to the root of the site.

The home page has 5 links on it. When the you look at the source from the generated page, 2 of the links are `https` and the other 3 `http` even though none have the base URL in the link data.

I have added `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';` to settings.php but that hasn't corrected the issue.

What is the proper way to force both tags to be generated with https: links?

Comment: Thank you Pierre! I usually have good luck with Google and it is rare I post a question. I have much to learn.

Comment: Voilà, now we have a real (+ good I think) question, +1. Only 1 more suggestion (if you don't mind): I ***guess*** the (rather critical) word ***all*** is still missing in your last phrase. Apart from that: I'd make that question also the title of your question (it's the summary of it all, no?). good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer, I believe it goes into great detail about enabling SSL support on pages and image assets for Drupal 7;

[How to force drupal 7 to load HTTPS assets?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169321/how-to-force-drupal-7-to-load-https-assets)

Also if your still having problems, take a look at this documentation on drupal.org;

https://www.drupal.org/https-information

Hope that helps!